# File stays in branch but never merges to other branches including master

Tags: git, merge, branch

Here's the goal I want to accomplish:

1)  Clone an existing repository

2)  Create a new branch

3)  Files are still based off master, including file.txt

4)  I make changes, including changing file.txt, and push up my changes to origin, including file.txt

5)  I am done with my branch and am ready to merge my branch into master, but I DONT want to merge file.txt.  One way is just not adding the file to my commits, but I want to ALWAYS ignore file.txt during merges, for any present and future branches if possible.

Whats the best way of accomplishing this?

I've thought of using gitignore, but I want this file to be in the branch in origin, so that the branch/file.txt is still completely shared between people.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, there's no good support in `git` to do what you're asking for. The software is made to efficiently merge two commits together, and one of the commits you're merging has `file.txt` as part of it's change-diff.

A work around that might be possible is to merge everything into `master`, including `file.txt` and then have another commit that deletes `file.txt` specifically.

You can do that manually a few times, but it's not a scalable process of course